# Is it possible to create an app that when installed the user can easily turn Bluetooth/NFC ON and OFF by double clicking the Home button?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm looking to create a shortcut to Bluetooth or NFC on Android+IOS,
preferably by "Double clicking the Home button." Is this possible?

If not possible are there other shortcuts? Like maybe double tapping the
mobile screen?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, as of 10 june 2015, it is not possible on non-jailbroken devices, as there is no public API that would expose the button actions to developer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override a click on the Home button on Android. If you want to double tap the screen for it, that's certainly possible. Just implement onTouchEvent in your application. You could also set up gestures or simply have a button.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

other than that, how it works is up to how you code it